# Concatenar dois arrays de acordo com seus respectivos índices

Tags: javascript, array

Eu tenho dois arrays, o primeiro sendo [a, c, e, g] e o segundo [b, d, f, h], por exemplo.

Eu quero concatenar estes dois arrays em uma respectiva ordem, formando: [ab, cd, ef, gh] ao invés do concat padrão, que seria [a, c, e, g, b, d, f, h]. Ou seja, o elemento do índice 0 do segundo array, eu quero que se junte ao elemento 0 do primeiro array, e o elemento 1 do segundo array, quero que se junte com o elemento 1 do primeiro array, assim respectitivamente.

O que eu tentei: Reduce, map e foreach. Por conta de eu ainda ser iniciante em lógica de programação, não consegui tirar a ideia do papel.

O meu código é o seguinte: Dois inputs. Cada array que eu demonstrei de exemplo representa os valores respectivos dos meus inputs (o primeiro array representa o primeiro input e o segundo, o segundo). Já que o array ele começa com um valor em branco, '', pois o usuário quem digitará o valor dele e exibirá na tela, eu não consegui realizar um for para cada índice, já que é um array oscilante.
Em uma parte da tela, eu tenho um span que irá mostrar o valor deste novo array que eu almejo.

Comment: *"O que eu tentei: Reduce, map e foreach"* coloca na pergunta o que já tentou

Comment: Do que adianta? Eu tentei e deu errado '-'

Comment: Se eu colocasse o que eu tentei ia ter que encher umas 30 linha de código feio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É só fazer um `for` e juntar os elementos.

```js
var array1 = ['a','c','e','g']
var array2 = ['b','d', 'f', 'h']

var array3 = []

for(let i in array1){
    array3.push(array1[i]+array2[i])
}

console.log(array3)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado meu jovem.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode intercalar dois arrays de mesmo comprimento usando o método [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para criar um array o elemento *n* é uma string composta pelos elementos *n* de *l1* e *l2*.

```js
l1 = ["a", "c", "e", "g"]
l2 = ["b", "d", "f", "h"]

//e= elemento, i= índice
l3 = l1.map((e, i) => `${e}${l2[i]}`);

console.log(l3);
```

Ou então use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) passando uma array vazio como valor inicial e com [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) povoe o resultado intercalando os dados.

```js
l1 = ["a", "c", "e", "g"]
l2 = ["b", "d", "f", "h"]

//r= resultado, e= elemento, i= índice
l3 = l1.reduce((r, e, i)=>{
  r.push(`${e}${l2[i]}`);
  return r
},[]);

console.log(l3);
```